# ColdFusion cfoutput query group

Tags: coldfusion

Please refer to this page: 
http://allblacks.01dev.co.nz/templates/super14/textobjects/SRMatchDayList.cfm
Query dump is included there. I've inherited this code and would prefer to work with it if possible.

The following code outputs fixtures by week.

```
<table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" align="center" width="530">
    <tr bgcolor="#797979">
        <th align="left"><p>&nbsp;<b>Date</b></p></td>
        <th align="left"><p><b>Game</b></p></td>
        <th align="left"><p><b>Venue</b></p></td>
        <th align="left"><p><b>Time (NZ)</b></p></td>
        <th align="center"><p><b>Result</b>&nbsp;</p></td>
    </tr>

    <cfset iWeekCounter = 0>
    <cfif not attributes.useSegmentTitle and attributes.sortDirection is "desc">
        <cfset qSegments = oSeries.getSegmentInfo(seriesID=attributes.seriesID)>
        <cfset iWeekCounter = qSegments.recordcount + 1>
    </cfif>

    <cfoutput query="qSeriesEvents" group="segmentID">
        <cfif attributes.sortDirection is "desc">
            <cfset iWeekCounter = iWeekCounter-1>
        <cfelse>
            <cfset iWeekCounter = iWeekCounter+1>
        </cfif>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="5"><p><br><strong>
                <cfif attributes.useSegmentTitle>
                    #qSeriesEvents.segment#
                <cfelse>
                    Week #iWeekCounter#
                </cfif>
            </strong></p></td>
        </tr>
        <cfoutput>
            <cfif textObjectCount gt 0>
                <tr>
                    <td><p>&nbsp;#DateFormat(eventDateTime, "dd mmm")#</p></td>
                    <td><p><a href="/index.cfm?layout=#attributes.eventLayout#&event=#eventID#">#event#</a></p></td>
                    <td><p>#location#</p></td>
                    <td><p><cfif showTimeField is 1>#lcase(timeFormat(dateadd('h',iTimeOffset,eventDateTime),"h:mm tt"))#</cfif></p></td>
                    <td align="center" valign="top"><p><cfif isDate(eventDateTime) AND dateDiff("n",eventDateTime, now())>#oEvent.getTeamResult(eventID, homeTeamID)#-#oEvent.getTeamResult(eventID, awayTeamID)#</cfif>&nbsp;</p></td>
                </tr>
                <tr><td colspan="5"><div style="height:1px; padding:0px; margin0px; font-size:0; border-bottom: 1px solid ##999"></div></td></tr>
            </cfif>
        </cfoutput>
    </cfoutput>
</table>
```

However, note weeks 3 - 18 in the above URL, which don't have any data. I don't want to display week lines if there is no data. How can I accomplish this using this query output "group=" setup if possible?

SQL from the website

```
SELECT tObj.textObjectCount, events.*, venues.venue, venues.location, DATENAME(wk, events.eventDateTime - 1) AS EventWeek, s.segment 
FROM events join segments s on s.segmentID = events.segmentID 
 LEFT OUTER JOIN (
  SELECT LUTextObjectEvent.eventID, COUNT(*) AS textObjectCount 
  FROM  LUTextObjectEvent 
   INNER JOIN textObjects ON LUTextObjectEvent.textObjectID = textObjects.textObjectID 
   GROUP BY LUTextObjectEvent.eventID
  ) tObj 
  ON events.eventID = tObj.eventID 
 LEFT OUTER JOIN venues ON events.venueID = venues.venueID 
WHERE (events.eventID IN (
 SELECT eventID 
 FROM events
 WHERE segmentID IN (
  SELECT segmentID 
  FROM segments 
  WHERE seriesID IN (?))
 )
) 
ORDER BY s.segmentID asc
```

Comment: Your query didn't dump.  Please edit your post to include the sql for that query.  If there is at least one game per week, the answer probably lies in the date range for that query.

Comment: You don't even want those rows in the query.  It looks like you're using a left join instead of an inner join(?). But without being able to see the SQL it is hard to help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're using a `LEFT OUTER JOIN` which means you'll have one record for every event/segment. Change those to inner joins and you should have your desired results

```
SELECT tObj.textObjectCount, events.*, venues.venue, venues.location, DATENAME(wk, events.eventDateTime - 1) AS EventWeek, s.segment 
FROM events join segments s on s.segmentID = events.segmentID 
 INNER JOIN (
  SELECT LUTextObjectEvent.eventID, COUNT(*) AS textObjectCount 
  FROM  LUTextObjectEvent 
   INNER JOIN textObjects ON LUTextObjectEvent.textObjectID = textObjects.textObjectID 
   GROUP BY LUTextObjectEvent.eventID
  ) tObj 
  ON events.eventID = tObj.eventID 
 INNER JOIN JOIN venues ON events.venueID = venues.venueID 
WHERE (events.eventID IN (
 SELECT eventID 
 FROM events
 WHERE segmentID IN (
  SELECT segmentID 
  FROM segments 
  WHERE seriesID IN (?)))) 
ORDER BY s.segmentID asc
```

Comment: Oh, if you click on the query dump it shows more information.  Who knew?

Comment: Nice, I didn't even see the dump on my phone.  Curse you mobile browser!